# SlickNav not correctly reading my nested structure

Tags: html, menu, html-lists, slicknav

I'm using slickNav and its not properly reading my nested list.

This page is a repository for NPCS for a Table top RPG.
The top level is general information and organizes NPCs by location. 
The second level organizes NPCs by rarity level 
and the third level is the NPC's themselves.

Now interestingly, slickNav displays levels 1 and 2 just fine, but level 3 opens up to invisible text. I say invisible text because the amount of space that is revealed by the dropdown is correct.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1eqd.jpg) GIF shows what i'm talking about. 
Observe how I click on Domestic animals, according the code below you can this is a long list of NPCs. The space SlickNav drops down is large. 
Then observe how I click under Eol, this part of the site is undeveloped still, and so its only list item is " coming soon". Accordingly slickNav only drops down a little to make enough space for that.

According to http://slicknav.com/, it seems ive correctly nested my structure and labeled the menu as class="menu".

Its worth noting that on other parts of the site this menu works fine, but the menu's on those parts of the site are maximum of two levels deep.

Here is my HTML: Warning this is a big menu

```
<div class ="menu_wrap"> 
<nav id = "navMenu">
<ul  class = "menu clearfix">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <ul class='subMenu1'>
            <li id="instr">Instructions</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>General
    <ul class="subMenu1" >
            <li>Domestic Animals
                <ul class="subMenu2">
                    <li id="da1">Camel</li>
                    <li id="da2">War Camel</li>
                    <li id="da3">Druldon</li>
                    <li id="da4">Donkey</li>
                    <li id="da5">Pony</li>
                    <li id="da6">Draft Horse</li>
                    <li id="da7">Saddle Horse</li>
                    <li id="da8">Light War Horse</li>
                    <li id="da9">Heavy War Horse</li>
                    <li id="da10">Chariot Horse</li>
                    <li id="da11">Voran War Horse</li>
                    <li id="da12">Elven Narathi</li>
                    <li id="da13">Mountain Ram</li>
                    <li id="da14">War Elephant</li>
                    <li id="da15">War Mammoth</li>
                    <li id="da16">Dovashi Mastiff</li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li>Common NPCs
                <ul class="subMenu2">
                    <li id="guard1">Guard: Dovashi</li>
                    <li id="guard2">Guard: Dwarven</li>
                    <li id="guard3">Guard: Elven</li>
                    <li id="guard4">Guard: Gamoran</li>
                    <li id="guard5">Guard: Salatai</li>
                    <li id="guard6">Guard: Voran</li>
                    <li id="guard7">Guard: Dark Elf</li>
                    <li id="c5">Gnoll</li>
                    <li id="c6">Grimlock</li>
                    <li id="c11">Roper</li>
                    <li id="c12">Skeleton</li>
                    <li id="c13">Giant Spider</li>
                    <li id="c15">Zombie</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Uncommon NPCs
                <ul class= "subMenu2">
                    <li id="uc5">Fire Child</li>
                    <li id="uc6">Ghoul</li>
                    <li id="uc11">Rakasa</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Rare NPCs
                <ul class= "subMenu2">
                    <li id="r1">Adherer</li>
                    <li id="uc24">Arcane</li>
                    <li id="r3">Bane Dead</li>
                    <li id="r5">Fire Lord</li>
                    <li id="eleGen">Generic Elementalist</li>
                    <li id="necGen">Generic Necromancer</li>
                    <li id="illGen">Generic Illusionist</li>
                    <li id="cleGen">Generic Cleric</li>
                    <li id="r8">Radasai Warrior</li>
                    <li id="r9">Elemental(Fire)</li>
                    <li id="r10">Elemental(Water)</li>
                    <li id="r11">Elemental(Earth)</li>
                    <li id="r12">Elemental(Air)</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Very Rare NPCs
                <ul class="subMenu2">
                    <li id="vr1">Arch Shadow</li>
                    <li id="vr3">Gorgon</li>
                    <li id="vr4">Illithid</li>
                    <li id="new3">Vampire</li>
                    <li id="new4">Were Wolf</li>

                </ul>
            </li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li id ="world_drop"> Wol
        <ul class ="subMenu1" >

                <li>Common NPCs

                            <ul class="subMenu2">
                                    <li id="c1">Cave Bear</li>
                                    <li id="c2">Dire Wolf</li>
                                    <li id="c3">Echuyan</li>
                                    <li id="c4">Goblin</li>
                                    <li id="c7">Voran Raider</li>
                                    <li id="c8">Dovashi Ronin</li>
                                    <li id="c9">Naga</li>
                                    <li id="c10">Orc</li>
                                    <li id="c14">Umber Hulk</li>

                            </ul>

                </li>
                <li>Uncommon NPCs
                    <ul class="subMenu2">
                                    <li id="uc1">Ant (Giant)</li>
                                    <li id="uc2">Alaghi</li>
                                    <li id="uc3">Centaur</li>
                                    <li id="uc4">Dire Boar</li>
                                    <li id="uc7">Ogre</li>
                                    <li id="uc8">Orc(Black)</li>
                                    <li id="uc9">Orc (Shaman)</li>
                                    <li id="uc10">Owl Bear</li>
                                    <li id="uc12">Rastipede</li>
                                    <li id="uc13">Troll</li>
                                    <li id="new1">Young Black Wyvern</li>
                            </ul>
                </li>


                <li>Rare NPCs
                        <ul class="subMenu2">   
                                    <li id="r2">Ant Lion( giant)</li>
                                    <li id="new2">Adult Black Wyvern</li>
                                    <li id="r4">Basilisk</li>
                                    <li id="r6">Hill Giant</li>
                                    <li id="r7">Naga Elite</li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>



                <li>Very Rare NPCs
                        <ul class="subMenu2">

                                    <li id="vr2">Dray</li>


                                    <li id="vr5">kalin</li>
                                    <li id="vr6">Naga Queen</li>
                                    <li id="vr7">Minotaur</li>

                            </ul>

                </li>   
        </ul>   
    </li>


<li> Nol
    <ul class="subMenu1">
            <li>Common NPCs
                    <ul class="subMenu2">
                            <li id="c16">Abrian</li>
                            <li id="c17">Cave Bear (Polar)</li>
                            <li id="c18">Dwarven Bandits</li>
                            <li id="c19">Ettin</li>
                            <li id="c20">Frost Orc</li>
                            <li id="c21">Tus'Khul</li>
                            <li id="c22">Icemaw Raiders</li>
                            <li id="c23">Kenku</li>
                            <li id="c24">Kobold</li>
                            <li id="c25">Tundra Stag</li>
                            <li id="c26">Wight</li>

                    </ul>
            </li>

            <li>Uncommon NPCs
                    <ul class="subMenu2">
                            <li id="uc14">Bainligor</li>
                            <li id="uc15">Ettin (Mage)</li>
                            <li id="uc16">Blue Orc</li>
                            <li id="uc17">Goatmen</li>
                            <li id="uc18">Ice Golem</li>
                            <li id="uc19">Rogue ClockWork</li>
                            <li id="uc20">Snow Serpent</li>
                            <li id="uc21">Ice Wyvern(Young)</li>
                            <li id="uc22">Voldun</li>
                    </ul>   
            </li>
            <li>Rare NPCs
                <ul class="subMenu2">
                        <li id="r13">Aviarag</li>
                        <li id="r14">Crystal Hydra</li>
                        <li id="r15">Dark Hood</li>
                        <li id="r16">Derro Warrior</li>
                        <li id="r17">Frost Giant</li>
                        <li id="r18">Gargoyle</li>
                        <li id="r19">Ice Wyvern(Adult)</li>
                        <li id="r20">Mammoth</li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Very Rare NPCs
                <ul class="subMenu2">
                    <li id="vr8">White Dragon</li>
                    <li id="vr9">Pit Horror</li>
                    <li id="vr10">Frozen Men</li>
                    <li id="vr11">Vaporighu</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>


<li id ="indie_drop"> Sol
        <ul class="subMenu1">
                <li>Common NPCs
                    <ul class="leftSubMenu2">
                        <li id="c27">Cistern Fiend</li>
                        <li id="c28">Dire Crocodile</li>
                        <li id="c29">Dire Lion</li>
                        <li id="c30">Gamoran Exiles</li>
                        <li id="c31">Giant Scorpion</li>
                        <li id="c32">Myconid</li>
                        <li id="c33">Sand Bones</li>
                        <li id="c34">Salatai Bandits</li>
                        <li id="c35">Shissai half Breed</li>
                        <li id="c36">Tus-Kowah</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Uncommon NPCs
                    <ul class="leftSubMenu2">
                        <li id="uc23">Amiq-Rasol</li>
                        <li id="uc25">Beholder-Kin</li>
                        <li id="uc26">Gremlin</li>
                        <li id="uc27">Lesser Salamander</li>
                        <li id="uc28">Mummy</li>
                        <li id="uc29">Scrab</li>
                        <li id="uc30">Spell-Sword Merc.</li>
                        <li id="uc31">Shissai Pure Blood</li>
                        <li id="uc32">Will-O-Wisp</li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Rare NPCs
                    <ul class="leftSubMenu2">
                        <li id="r21">Assimar</li>
                        <li id="r22">Elephant</li>
                        <li id="r23">Hattori</li>
                        <li id="r24">Roc</li>
                        <li id="r25">Sand-Men</li>
                        <li id="r26">Skordi</li>
                        <li id="r27">Tortle</li>
                        <li id="r28">Winged Snake</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Very Rare NPCs
                    <ul class="leftSUbMenu2">
                        <li id="vr12">Beholder</li>
                        <li id="vr13">Black Dragon</li>
                        <li id="vr15">Djinn</li>
                        <li id="vr14">Mummy Lord</li>
                        <li id="vr16">Sand Hydra</li>


                    </ul>
                </li>

        </ul>
</li>

<li> Eol
    <ul class="subMenu1">
            <li>Common NPCs
                <ul class="leftSUbMenu2">
                    <li>Comming Soon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Uncommon NPCs
                <ul class="leftSUbMenu2">
                    <li>Comming Soon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li>Rare NPCs
                <ul class="leftSUbMenu2">
                    <li>Comming Soon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li>Very Rare NPCs
                <ul class="leftSUbMenu2">
                    <li>Comming Soon</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
    </ul>   
</li>
 </ul>
```

This is all the CSS associated with the Menu. 
Note: This is a simple CSS menu, the submenus are set to display:none and on hover the display is set to block.

All my menus work the same way on other parts of the site. But display being set to none is the only thing I can think of.

```
#navMenu{
margin:0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
line-height: 2em;
top: 28%;
left: 5.1%;
width: 100%;
font-size: 1.2vw;
font-family: verdana,arial,serif;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 3;




}





#navMenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 2vw;




}

#navMenu li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
background: #999;
padding:.5em;

}
#navMenu ul li {
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
height: 1.875em;
width:13.5vw;
display: block;
color: #e0e0da;
background: black;
border-color: #99cdde; 
border: 1px solid #99cdde;




}


.subMenu1,.subMenu2{
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 100%;
left: -.25%; /*this fixes a menu alignment problem */
cursor: pointer;
}


.subMenu2{
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0%;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
height: 30vh;
}
.leftSubMenu2{
position: absolute;
right: 100%;
top: 0%;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
height: 30vh;
display: none;
}



#navMenu ul li:hover>ul {
display: block;

}

#navMenu ul li:hover{
transition:all linear .15s;
color: #99cdde;

}
```

Comment: You can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/eq0Lgakj/ - that's it is displaying the 3rd level correctly. Perhaps some other CSS is overriding the font color? When you get to the 3rd level, is the menu text there if you inspect the it in your browser?

Comment: I have updated the original Post to include all the  CSS that concerns the menu. 

And upon inspection, yes, the List items are all accounted for.

Comment: The problem was css pushing the sublevel menu off screen.